# Unable to pass variable from shell script to perl script

Tags: perl, bash, shell

I have a shell script which passes the some variables to perl script, named Deploy.pl. But it seems perl script is not picking the variable. I have been trying to find out the cause but unable to resolve it. Same variables are getting passed to perl script properly except the **$entname** variable. Same varibale i am using for my copy statement,but as it is not getting picked up by perl script i am getting an cannot find path error. Please have a look at both shell script and perl script. I know it's insane to put such a long script,but i want to give clear idea about what is happening with the script.

Shell Script:

```
     #!/bin/bash

sleep 1
echo "#####  Please Read the following information carefully  ####"
sleep 2
echo "Please read this preamble in order to run the script. It states the adamant requirement that user needs to  have while executing the script."
echo " "
echo "1. The script requires the user name(i.e. TIBID ) which should have SVN access in order to execute it successfully. Example: ./deploy.sh tib7826"
echo " "
echo "where tib7826 is the user who has SVN access. Make sure the tibid you are using should have full SVN access."
echo " "
echo "2. The script further requires the Internal name as input. MDM creates a directory in the MQ_COMMON_DIR with internal name.It is" 
echo " "
echo "case-sensitive and should be exact as what it is there in MQ_COMMON_DIR."
echo " "
echo "3. Further it asks for envoirnment name. The  Environment name should be like DEV1,DEV2,DEV3,TEST1,TEST2 etc.Make sure they too are case specific."
echo "Otherwise it will fail to execute further steps."
echo " "
echo " 4. The script requires  CATALOG ID's as a input for the below 4 repositories"
echo " "
echo " a.ITEM_MASTER"
echo " "
echo " b.DISTRIBUTION_FACILITY_LV"
echo " "
echo " c.MANAGEMENT_DIVISION_SOI"
echo " "
echo " d.ALTERNATE IDENTIFICATIONS"
echo " "
echo "You will get those ID's from MDM Web UI. Login to the MDM UI. Go to Item Data==>Repositories==>ID Column."
echo " "
echo "5. For more detail read the Readme.txt in order to execute this script.Take it from the location"
echo " "
echo "/tibco/data/GRISSOM2/build_deploy_scripts_kroger/document"
echo " "
echo " Or  else take the ReadMe form SVN."
echo " "
echo "If you agree to execute the script press Y else N."
read uinput
if [ $uinput == 'Y' ]; then
echo "Script will execute!!"
sleep 3
else
echo "You have Cancel the Agreement"
exit
fi




# sample command to execute the deploy script ./deploy.sh tib7777

# export the build root
export BUILD_ROOT=/tibco/data/GRISSOM2

# CUSTOM env variables are temporary and set directly in the script to execute custom tasks
export CUSTOM1=/tibco/data/GRISSOM2/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS/common/MDR_ITEM_E1/rulebase

cd $BUILD_ROOT/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS/common


echo "--- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - "
echo "Enter your Enterprise INTERNAL NAME:"
sleep 1
read internal_name

sleep 2

echo "Enter Enterprise Name"

read entname

#code to check if the Enterprise with the correct INTERNAL name exists

if [ -d "$MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name" ]; then
echo "Artifacts for the $internal_name will be deployed"
else
echo "THE ENTERPRISE with the $internal_name doesn't seems to be correct INTERNAL NAME. Execute the script again with the correct INTERNAL NAME"
exit
fi


#This snippet will cleanup the existing MDR_ITME_E1 before we get the latest code for MDR_ITME_E1 enterprise from SVN

cd $BUILD_ROOT/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS/common
if [ -d "$entname" ]; then
rm -rf $BUILD_ROOT/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS/common/$entname
echo "Removing existing $entname from SVN source directory.."
echo "..."
sleep 1
echo "...."
sleep 1
echo "....."
sleep 1
else
echo "$entname Doesn't Exist for the first time"
fi

echo "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"

echo "Retrieving Latest Code from SVN..."
sleep 2

echo "Please wait......"
echo "Connecting to SVN."
sleep 1
echo "Connecting to SVN.."
sleep 1
echo "Connecting to SVN..."
sleep 1
echo "Connecting to SVN...."
sleep 1
echo "Connecting to SVN....."
sleep 1
echo "Connecting to SVN......"
sleep 1
echo "Connecting to SVN......."
sleep 1
echo "Connecting to SVN........"

echo "Do you want to checkout the latest version of the COMMON DIR code [Y] or [N]"
read svninput

if [ $svninput == 'Y' ]; then

echo "Downloading SVN Code"

                     if [ $entname ==  'MDR_ITEM_E1' ]; then

echo svn co --username $1 http://svn.kroger.com/repos/mercury/tibcomdm/cim_paris/branches/Grissom2_Development/common/MDR_ITEM_E1
svn co --username $1 http://svn.kroger.com/repos/mercury/tibcomdm/cim_paris/branches/Grissom2_Development/common/MDR_ITEM_E1
sleep 3
                     else 
echo "Copying E2 code"

echo svn co --username $1  http://svn.kroger.com/repos/mercury/tibcomdm/cim_paris/branches/Grissom2_breakfix/common/MDR_ITEM_E2
svn co --username $1  http://svn.kroger.com/repos/mercury/tibcomdm/cim_paris/branches/Grissom2_breakfix/common/MDR_ITEM_E2

                     fi

else
echo "Enter the revision number of the common directory"
read revision
                     if [ $entname ==  'MDR_ITEM_E1' ]; then

svn co --username $1 -r $revision http://svn.kroger.com/repos/mercury/tibcomdm/cim_paris/branches/Grissom2_Development/common/MDR_ITEM_E1
                     else
echo "E2 Code"
svn co --username $1 -r $revision http://svn.kroger.com/repos/mercury/tibcomdm/cim_paris/branches/Grissom2_breakfix/common/MDR_ITEM_E2     
                     fi

echo "Loaded code for Enterprise"

fi



if [ -d $BUILD_ROOT/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS/common/$entname ] ; then
echo "Downloaded latest code from SVN!!"
else
echo "CODE has not been downloaded. Please check your credentials."
exit  
fi


#echo svn co --username $1 http://svn.kroger.com/repos/mercury/tibcomdm/cim_paris/branches/Grissom2_Development/common/MDR_ITEM_E1

#svn co --username $1 http://svn.kroger.com/repos/mercury/tibcomdm/cim_paris/branches/Grissom2_Development/common/MDR_ITEM_E1

echo "========================================"

echo "Taking destination organization backup...wait"

cd $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name
chmod -Rf 777 $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name
sleep 2
cp -rf /$MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name /$MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name$( date +%d%m%Y%H%M )
echo "backup done!!" 
chmod -Rf 775 $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name *   
echo "========================================"

#Removing  contents inside the workflow,forms,maps,rules,rulebase,schema,templates,inputmap
sleep 2
echo "Removing contents inside workflow,inputmap,rules......"
echo "."
sleep 1
echo ".."
sleep 1
echo "..."
sleep 1

if [ -d "$MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name" ]; then

# cleanup the enterprise internal directories  
rm -rf $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/workflow/*

rm -rf $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/forms/*

rm -rf $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/rulebase/*

rm -rf $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/maps/*

rm -rf $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/templates/*

else
echo "THE ENTERPRISE with the $internal_name internal name does not exist. Execute the script with the correct INTERNAL NAME"
exit
fi

sleep 2
echo "The following folders[workflow, forms, rulebase, maps, templates]   have been cleaned up in the Enterprise common directory"

cd $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name

echo "Inside internal enterprise"
echo "-------------"

echo "InputMap,Schema,Scheduler,Distributedlock...Creating!!"
sleep 2


if [ -d "inputmap" ] && [ -d "schema" ] && [ -d "scheduler" ] && [ -d "distributedlock" ]; then
echo "Copying the directory structure"
echo "inputmap, schema,scheduler,distributedlock exists!!"

else

mkdir inputmap
mkdir schema
mkdir scheduler
mkdir distributedlock
chmod 775 *.*

sleep 1
echo "Required additional directories have been created!"
fi

#Enter Environment Name:    

echo "Options: Which Enviroment you want to Deploy 1.DEV1 2.DEV2 3.DEV3 4.TEST1 5.TEST2 6.E2E 7.STAGE 8.PRODUCTION"

echo "Enter Environment Name:"
read env_name
if [ $env_name == DEV1 -o  $env_name == DEV2 -o  $env_name == DEV3 -o $env_name == TEST1 -o $env_name == TEST2 -o $env_name == E2E -o  $env_name == STAGE -o $env_name == PRODUCTION ] ; then
echo "Running"
else
echo "You Entered wrong Environment Name!! Enter correct environment name and run the script again."
exit
fi

#Input catalog ID's==specific to E1 enterprise code only

if [ $entname == 'MDR_ITEM_E1' ]; then

echo "Enter Catalog ID's to copy the CV and Catalogvalidation files"

echo "Enter Catalog ID For ITEM_MASTER"
read item
       if [ -d "$MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/catalog/master/$item" ]; then
echo "renaming existing catalogvalidation.xml as a backup copy"
cd $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/catalog/master/$item
mv catalogvalidation.xml catalogvalidation.xml$( date +%d%m%Y%H%M )
       else
echo "Either directory or file does not exist"
       fi

echo "Enter Catalog ID For DISTRIBUTION_FACILITY_LV"
read dflv
       if [ -d "$MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/catalog/master/$dflv" ]; then
echo "renaming existing catalogvalidation.xml as a backup copy"
cd $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/catalog/master/$dflv
mv catalogvalidation.xml catalogvalidation.xml$( date +%d%m%Y%H%M )
       else
echo "Either directory or file does not exist"
       fi

echo "Enter Catalog ID For MANAGEMENT_DIVISION_SOI"
read mds
       if [ -d "$MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/catalog/master/$mds" ]; then
echo "renaming existing catalogvalidation.xml as a backup copy"
cd $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/catalog/master/$mds
mv catalogvalidation.xml catalogvalidation.xml$( date +%d%m%Y%H%M )
       else
echo "Either directory or file does not exist"
       fi


echo "Enter Catalog ID For ALTERNATE_IDENTIFICATION_MVL"
read aim
       if [ -d "$MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/catalog/master/$aim" ]; then
echo "renaming existing catalogvalidation.xml as a backup copy"
cd $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/catalog/master/$aim
mv catalogvalidation.xml catalogvalidation.xml$( date +%d%m%Y%H%M )
       else
echo "Either directory or file does not exist"
       fi

echo "Copying CV Files"

cp -rf  $BUILD_ROOT/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS/common/MDR_ITEM_E1/catalog/master/34731_ITEM_MASTER/cv_* $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/rulebase/
cp -rf  $BUILD_ROOT/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS/common/MDR_ITEM_E1/catalog/master/34800_DISTRIBUTION_FACILITY_LV/cv_* $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/rulebase/
cp -rf  $BUILD_ROOT/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS/common/MDR_ITEM_E1/catalog/master/34800_DISTRIBUTION_FACILITY_LV/DISTRIBUTION_FACILITY_LV.xml $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/rulebase/
cp -rf  $BUILD_ROOT/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS/common/MDR_ITEM_E1/catalog/master/34801_MANAGEMENT_DIVISION_SOI/cv_* $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/rulebase/
#cp -rf  $BUILD_ROOT/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS/common/MDR_ITEM_E1/catalog/master/ALTERNATE_IDENTIFICATION_MVL/cv_* $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/rulebase/
sleep 3
echo "....."
sleep 1 
echo "......."
sleep 1 
echo "........."
echo "Copied CV files"

#Copying  E2 Specific Code--Customized Files
else
#Copy E2 files
sleep 3

echo "Running the Deploy.pl..."
sleep 4

fi
# run the deploy script

cd $BUILD_ROOT/build_deploy_scripts_kroger/deploy_script

./Deploy.pl $env_name $item $dflv $mds $aim MDR_ITEM_E2 $internal_name


# custom code changes
# custom1 to change the rulebase URLs
echo " "
echo " "
echo "********************"

echo "========================================"

if [ $entname == 'MDR_ITEM_E1' ]; then
echo "Copying schema for $internal_name internal enterprise name"

if [ $env_name == DEV3 -o  $env_name == TEST2 -o  $env_name == DEV2 ]; then
echo "Copying $env_name schema"
cd /tibco/mdm/8.3/common/$internal_name/schema/

rm *.*
cp /tibco/data/GRISSOM2/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS/common/MDR_ITEM_E1/schema/TEST2/* /tibco/mdm/8.3/common/$internal_name/schema/

else
        if [ $env_name == E2E ]; then
        echo "Copying schema for $env_name environment!!"
        cd /tibco/mdm/8.3/common/MDRITME1/schema/
        rm *.*
        cp /tibco/data/GRISSOM2/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS/common/MDR_ITEM_E1/schema/E2E/* /tibco/mdm/8.3/common/$internal_name/schema/
        else
        echo "Incorrect environment name"
        exit
        fi
fi

echo "========================================="

else
echo "E2 code is deploying..."
fi




if [ $entname == 'MDR_ITEM_E1' ]; then

echo "Do you want to copy DropZone press Y to continue else N"
read dr
if [ "$dr" == 'Y' ]; then
echo "Copying DropZone"
cp -rf /tibco/data/GRISSOM2/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS/common/MDR_ITEM_E1/DropZone/* $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/DropZone/
echo "Copied DropZone"
sleep 1
else
echo "either folder doesn't exist in $internal_name or You have cancelled the copy opeeation for DropZone"
fi


echo "Do you want to copy EAI press Y to continue else N"
read eai
if [ "$eai" == 'Y' ]; then
echo "Copying EAI"
cp -rf /tibco/data/GRISSOM2/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS/common/MDR_ITEM_E1/EAI/* $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name/EAI/
echo "Copyied EAI"
sleep 1
else
echo "either folder doesn't exist in $internal_name or You have cancelled the copy opeeation for DropZone"
fi


else
echo "#$%#$%#$%#$%#$%&*^&*#@$"
fi

cd $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name

echo "****** The following directories have been deployed to your Enterprise Internal directory ********"
echo "        "

echo "======================================"
ls | tee -a 
echo "======================================="

 #change the permissions back to standard on the internal directory 

#chmod -Rf 775 $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name 
cd $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name
chmod -Rf 644 *

cd $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;

cd $MQ_COMMON_DIR/$internal_name
chmod -Rf 777 EAI
chmod -Rf 777 DropZone
chmod -Rf 777 distributedlock

echo "Permissions changed!"
echo "========================================"
echo " "
echo " "
echo " "
echo "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"
echo "Deployed resources successfully"
echo "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"
echo " "
echo " "
exit
```

Perl script:

```
      #!/usr/bin/perl


use CIMDeploymentVaribles;

&main;



sub main()

{ 

       print "\n Deployment  Script \n\n\n";

       #print "Options: Which Enviroment you want to Deploy\n 1.DEV1\n 2.DEV2\n 3.TEST1\n 4.TEST2\n 5.STAGE\n 6.PRODUCTION \n\n";

               $dep_env = $ARGV[0];
              $item_master = $ARGV[1];
              $distribution_facility_lv = $ARGV[2];
              $management_division_soi = $ARGV[3];
              $altername_identification_mvl = $ARGV[4];
              $entname = $ARGV[5];
              $internal_name = $ARGV[6];

                     $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION = "/tibco/data/GRISSOM2/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS";
                     $SCRIPT_LOCATION = "$SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/build_deploy_scripts_kroger/deploy_script";

                     if ($dep_env eq 'DEV1' || $dep_env eq 'DEV2'|| $dep_env eq 'TEST1' || $dep_env eq 'TEST2' || $dep_env eq 'STAGE'|| $dep_env eq 'PRODUCTION' || $dep_env eq 'LOCALDEV1' || $dep_env eq 'MAHANADI'|| $dep_env eq 'DEV3' || $dep_env eq 'E2E')
                     {

                                   print "\n Deployment on Environment:: $dep_env\n";

                                   &Set_Environment_Variables($dep_env);
                                   &display_variables($dep_env);
                                   &Deploy_Common_dir_artifacts($dep_env);

                     }

                     else
                     {
                            print "\nWrong argument is passed\n";
                            print " \n Provide valid argument: DEV1 or DEV2 or TEST1 or TEST2 or STAGE or PRODUCTION\n\n";
                            exit;
                     }
}


sub display_variables()
{

       print "\n Displaying Variables Start\n";

       print "\n MQ_HOME on $_[0] :: $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_HOME'}\n";
       print "\n MQ_COMMON_DIR on $_[0] :: $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}\n";
       print "\n ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME in $_[0] :: $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}\n";
       print "\n SCRIPT_LOCATION in $SCRIPT_LOCATION\n";
       print "\n SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION in $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION\n";

       print "\n Displaying Variables Ended \n";

}
sub Set_Environment_Variables()
{

       print "\n Setting up environment Variables\n";

       $ENV{"MQ_HOME"}="$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_HOME'}";

       $ENV{"MQ_COMMON_DIR"}="$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}";

       print "\nEnvironment Variables are set\n";

}


sub Deploy_Common_dir_artifacts()
{

       print "\n Deploying common dir aftifacts for $_[0] environment \n";

       print "\nDeploying common dir artifacts to specific enterprise ( $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'} ) \n";

       print "Command: rm -rf `find $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION -type d -name .svn`";

       system("rm -rf `find $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION -type d -name .svn`");

       # Deploying forms

       print "\n 1. Deploying forms \n";

       print "\nExecuting::: cp $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/common/$entname/forms/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/forms/\n";

       system("cp $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/common/$entname/forms/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/forms/");

       # Deploying maps

       print "\n 2. Deploying maps \n";

       print "\nExecuting::: cp $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/common/$entname/maps/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/maps/ \n";

       system("cp $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/common/$entname/maps/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/maps/");

       # Deploying rulebase

       print "\n 3. Deploying rulebase \n";

       print "\nExecuting::: cp -r $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/common/$entname/rulebase/*        $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/rulebase/\n";

       system("cp -r $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/common/$entname/rulebase/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/rulebase/");

       print "\n\n Executing ::: find $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/rulebase/* -type f -exec sed -i 's/$internal_name/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/' {} \\;";

       system("find $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/rulebase/* -type f -exec sed -i 's/$internal_name/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/' {} \\;");

       # Deploying workflow

       print "\n 4. Deploying workflow \n";

       print "\nExecuting::: cp -r $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/common/$entname/workflow/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/workflow/\n";

       system("cp -r $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/common/$entname/workflow/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/workflow/");

       print "\n\n Executing ::: find $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/workflow/* -type f -exec sed -i 's/MDR_NEW/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/' {} \\;";

       system("find $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/workflow/* -type f -exec sed -i 's/$internal_name/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/' {} \\;");

       # Deploying htmlprops

       print "\n 6. Deploying htmlprops \n";

       # print "\nExecuting::: cp $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/common/$entname/htmlprops/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/htmlprops/\n";

       #system("cp -rf $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/common/$entname/htmlprops/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/htmlprops/");

       # Deploying templates

       print "\n 7. Deploying Templates \n";

       print "\nExecuting::: cp $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/common/$entname/templates/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/templates/\n";

       system("cp $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/common/$entname/templates/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/templates/");

       # Deploying Schedular

       print "\n 8. Deploying scheduler \n";

       print "\nExecuting::: cp -r $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/common/$entname/scheduler $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/\n";

       #system("cp -r $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/common/$entname/scheduler/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/scheduler/");

       # Deploying Filewatcher

       print "\n 9. Deploying Filewatcher \n";

       print "\nExecuting::: cp $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/config/FileWatcher.xml $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_HOME'}/config/\n";

       system("cp $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/config/FileWatcher.xml $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_HOME'}/config/");

       # Deploying Custom Properties

       # print "\n 5. Deploying Custom Properties \n";

       # print "\nExecuting::: cp -r $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/custom/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_HOME'}/custom/\n";

       # system("cp -r $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/custom/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_HOME'}/custom/");

       # Deploying dynservices

       print "\n 10. Deploying dynservices \n";

       print "\nExecuting::: cp -r $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/dynservices $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_HOME'}/\n";

       #system("cp -r $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/dynservices $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_HOME'}/");


       # Deploying InputMap

       print "\n 12. Deploying InputMap \n";

       print "\nExecuting::: cp -r $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/inputmap/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_HOME'}/inputmap/\n";

       #system("cp -r $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/schema/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_HOME'}/schema/");
       system("cp -r $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/common/$entname/inputmap/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/inputmap/");

       # Deploying DistributeLock

       print "\n 13. Deploying DistributedLock \n";

       print "\nExecuting::: cp -r $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/distributedlock/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_HOME'}/distributedlock/\n";

       #system("cp -r $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/schema/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_HOME'}/schema/");
       system("cp -r $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/common/$entname/distributedlock/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/distributedlock/");

}
```

Failure:  print "\nExecuting::: cp $SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION/common/**$entname**/forms/* $ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'MQ_COMMON_DIR'}/$ENV_Variables{\"$_[0]\"}{'ENTERPRISE_INTERNAL_NAME'}/forms/\n";

As $entname is not picked up it's not copying expected files.

Comment: You were right: it is insane to post such a long script.  And most of it is irrelevant.  Make a minimal example.

Comment: I agree. Posting such a large and irrelevant code sample is not a good idea, because it seems like your effort is minimal. Point straight at the problem, and if someone wants more context, let them ask.

Comment: I don't see how you can tell "$entname is not picked up" from the output when you also get `$SVN_COMMON_DIR_LOCATION` - it seems that no variable is being expanded.

Comment: yes my bad,it has been resolved by exporting through package file. I wasn't aware of it as it was made by some other fellow.Thanks all for your critics and suggestion i'll make sure to keep my doubts as minimum as i can. Sorry for trouble from my heart.

Answer (score 3):

You really need to start quoting your scripts propertly:

```
rm -rf $BUILD_ROOT/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS/common/$entname
```

Imagine I enter `MDR_ITEM_E1 /`. The command would now delete all the files on your disk.